# Rights of node.js installation

Tags: node.js, windows-server-2008-r2

What are the **right necessities** which we do have for the installation of the ***node.js*** on a server there? And what is the installation will be made for ***every user*** (session on the server) or ***global*** ?
In the first one there is configuration to be made? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need the Windows installer from the Node.js site.

Perhaps you may set the binary path in the system environment variable to enable node for all user. I don't remember what the installer do exactly for the PATH.

Comment: Thx, do you have an idea on the necessary permissions to install it?

Comment: In theory with MSI file you need the admin permissions. I don't use Node on Windows server but I think it such as XP or 7. There isn't special mention on documentations about it. See here: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation